# Both client-side and server-side validation for my game

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I'm making a multiplayer game, where players (1 up to 4) put items on the board (multiple items per move are permitted) one by another. The game is ajax-based. The rules of placing items on the board are pretty complicated, plenty of combinations are forbidden.

What I want to achieve is performing moves validations immediately when player places his item on the board, so there's no lag. He knows if his move is valid or not in no time. Then, the same rules are being checked on server-side, once the move is submitted. This is of course for security reasons, to deal with ajax spoofing. What I'm sending in the request is just a map of items IDs and fields indexes. On the server I'm checking tons of stuff, including whether all those items belong to the player who is permitted to move now and if those items can be put on these particular fields.

I'm thinking about the best practice to validate fields indexes. Now, I have two completely separate scripts, JavaScript one and PHP one. Is there any way to make it more flexible, so if I decide to change the rules, I could change it on both sides? I know I could do some rules mapping object and then write interpreters for both sides, but those rules are too complicated to work with any map like that.

Comment: you could generate the javascript by PHP. That way you at least had your rules in the same file.

Comment: "Rules" generally are called "business rules". If you have a lot of those, the order gets important. typically, you'd start with the one that is the fastest with the highest probability to fail, the last one would be the slowest. This way you can speed up the whole validation. You can also add validation "onChange" instead of "onClick", don't know if this is practical in your case.

Comment: @Burki exactly what I wanted to suggest... But it may be hard to write the JS depending on rules in PHP... the only way I see is writing the JS and the PHP file at the same place, and then include dynamicly the PHP file for rules... ?

Comment: I am not sure if it can be determined from the information you gave wether or not it is feasible to somehow auto-generate the relevant parts of your JS. I personally would simply give it a try and see where it ends.

Comment: It would require alot of work to make all of your tasks into as simple as possible but that way you could call the needed javascript functions from javascript instead of outting all the javascript in the php file.

Comment: I think that all rules should be server side they may be checked on client side using small and fast ajax requests before submitting them to the server and double checked again after submitting them I understand that you worry about ajax spoofing but what about java-script changes made on client side also if you write rules in java-script they will be visible to everyone thus easier to understand for attacker you should keep things simple and make php validator class in one place and make it accessible by ajax

Comment: @Zgr3doo those rules are no secret, they can be visible in JavaScript. I don't care about JavaScript spoofing, because it has no effect on the game itself, because the player won't save anything invalid on the server, thanks to precise server-side validation. Ajax validation is not the best idea, because items are places quickly and this lag is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.

You could write all your game rule logic in a separate Javascript file in an easy to consume way.. Since this can be run on the client side that problem is out of the way.. And then using this (se link) PHP functionality call the same javascript code from within PHP and test moves for validity.

http://php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php

This way you can write your rules once and run them on both sides without having to rewrite them.

---

If you cant do something like this I would make the server calculate all possible moves for each game piece at the start of each round and send them to the client to present as possible actions. This way you client has no game logic but can still present valid moves without making queries for each one.

This also has the benefit of only having your rules on the server side and not letting people in to the details of how you are checking them.

Comment: This is very interesting, I will check it out!